# Hide animated content behind other elements

Tags: css, angular, animation, ionic-framework

I have created a page that hides a group of colors that the user can select. When the user clicks or taps "Chat Color" the group becomes visible with an animation that slides the group down. However, the animation shows the group sliding down over other content.

This is my animation CSS:

```
.slideDown {
    animation-name: slideDown;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideDown;

    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;

    visibility: visible !important;
    z-index: -1000 //TRIED CHANGING Z-INDEX
}

@keyframes slideDown {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(-2%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

How can I keep my animation but only display the group when it is not over other content?

I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-lgaqht).

Comment: you can have default opacity:0 the in the slideDown 50% you can up to 0.5 then in 100% set it to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try wrapping the `.slideDown` element in an overflow hidden.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden">
<ion-grid *ngIf="colorsExpanded" [ngClass]="{'slideDown': colorsExpanded}">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #7484ad" id="#7484ad" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#7484ad'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #32db64" id="#32db64" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#32db64'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #910d9b" id="#910d9b" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#910d9b'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #b00908" id="#b00908" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#b00908'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #2bc6d1" id="#2bc6d1" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#2bc6d1'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #216d0b" id="#216d0b" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#216d0b'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #d88219" id="#d88219" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#d88219'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #ed48c6" id="#ed48c6" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#ed48c6'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #0e0e49" id="#0e0e49" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#0e0e49'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #5b5b5b" id="#5b5b5b" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#5b5b5b'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #000000" id="#000000" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#000000'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
    <ion-col class="coloroption" style="background: #1213dd" id="#1213dd" (click)="selectcolor($event)"><span *ngIf="selectedcolor == '#1213dd'" class="check">&#10003;</span></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</div>
```